# where to add gesture detector on gridview displaying images

Tags: flutter, dart, gridview, gesture

I have successfully displaying images in a gridView()
but now, I want each image clickable/tappable,
I have tried putting gesture detector inside children but it does not seems to work,
pls help.

```
        import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
        import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
        import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
        import 'package:cached_network_image/cached_network_image.dart';

        class SearchTiles extends StatefulWidget {
          final String Image1 ="https://www.image1.png";
          final String Image2 ="https://www.image2.png";
          final String Image3 = "https://www.image3.png";
          final String Image3 = "https://www.image4.png";


          @override
          _SearchTilesState createState() => _SearchTilesState();
        }

        class _SearchTilesState extends State<SearchTiles> {
          @override
          Widget build(BuildContext context) {
            final title = 'Pick a Store';

            return MaterialApp(
              title: title,
              home: Scaffold(
                appBar: AppBar(
                  title: Text(title),
                ),
                body: GridView.count(
                    crossAxisCount: 2,
                    children: <String>[
                      widget.image1,
                      widget.image2,
                      widget.image3,
                      widget.image4
                    ].map((String url) {
                      return GridTile(
                        child: Image.network(
                          url,
                        ),
                      );
                    }).toList()),
              ),
            );
          }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Try this, It's work for me :-)
>
> ```
> return GridTile(
>   child: InkWell(
>     onTap: () {
>       //here get image tap callback
>     },
>     child: Image.network(
>       url,
>     ),
>   ),
> );
> ```

Comment: thanks @Rohit, works like a charm , appreciate quick response.

Answer (score 3):

Wrap the `GridTile` with `GestureDetector`, that way each GridTile will tappable